How to add a number on every page?
I'm looking to incorporate page numbers into my document for better navigation. At the moment, I've managed to display 'Page 1', but as the document flows onto subsequent pages, I want the numbering to continue incrementing. Additionally, I'm facing challenges in positioning the page numbers neatly in the bottom right corner.
# Function to fetch employee data from SQLite database
def fetch_employee_data(database_file, fromdate, todate):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("brgydb.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # Execute a query to retrieve records within the date range
    query = "SELECT lastname || ', ' || firstname, address, mobileno FROM employee WHERE datehired BETWEEN ? AND ?"
    cursor.execute(query, (fromdate, todate))

    employee_data = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return employee_data
def generate_pdf(employee_data, output_file):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(output_file, pagesize=letter, topMargin=50)

    def footer(canvas, doc):
        pageNumber = canvas.getPageNumber()
        canvas.saveState()
        canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 9)
        if pageNumber == 1:  # First page
            text = "Page 1"
        else:  # Second page onwards
            text = f"Page {pageNumber - 1}" 
        text_width = stringWidth(text, 'Helvetica', 9)  
        canvas.drawString(doc.width - inch * 0.5 - text_width, 0.15 * inch, text)  
        canvas.restoreState()

    # Create a frame for the footer
    frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='normal')
    template = PageTemplate(id='test', frames=[frame], onPage=footer)
    doc.addPageTemplates([template])
    
    elements = []

    chart_style = TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER')])
    image1 = Image("provineofrizal.png", width=80, height=80) 
    image2 = Image("brgylogo.jpg", width=80, height=80) 
    bold_style = ParagraphStyle('BoldText', fontName='Helvetica-Bold', fontSize=15, alignment=1, spaceBefore=10)

    # Write text to the canvas
    text = "<b>COMPANY NAME</b><br/><br/>EMPLOYEE REPORT LIST<br/><br/>Whatever text you put<br/>"
    p = Paragraph(text, bold_style)
    
    elements.append(Table([[image1, p, image2]],
                          colWidths=[3.3 * inch, 3.3 * inch, 3.3 * inch],
                          rowHeights=[2.5 * inch], style=chart_style))
    elements.append(Spacer(1, 15))
    
    # Define table data
    data = [['Employee Name', 'Mobile No', 'Address']]
    data.append(['--------------------', '--------------------', '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'])  # Separator line
    for employee in employee_data:
 
        data.append([employee[0], employee[2][:200], employee[1]])

    # Define table style 
    style = TableStyle([('FONT', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
                        ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.white)])

    # Create table object
    table = Table(data)

    # Apply style to table
    table.setStyle(style)
    elements.append(table)

    # Build PDF
    doc.build(elements)


what happens though? what's the error. Is it not showing "Page 2" etc. what is it showing?

yes its not showing page 2 etc.,

please describe this better. E.g. what is showing instead. Area there any error messages in the logs. etc. Right now, I have no idea HOW it is breaking. Because just looking quickly at the code I don't see anything wrong

I would also recommend putting some print statements or debug the code yourself, for example, what is the value of pageNumber when it isn't showing the page 2. Maybe it isn't 3 like you suspect

or maybe it is being drawn off screen/ at the wrong coordinates.

there is no error, page 2 isnt showing and beyond, when employee data fills up the first page. I only get "page 1

again, what is the value of pageNumber like I asked? but from this new info it sounds like the whole pagination system is not working. Not really to do with the page number appearing specifically.

it prints "Page Number: 1" despite it having 2 pages
